# Generate x number of objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, variable-declaration

1. **A desired x number of objects is to be created.**
2. **The system creates x number of objects.**

```js
for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {

  let obj = new Object()

}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how this can be done without the objects having the same name. I thought that naming them obj1 to objx using iteration to avoid conflicting names is a solution. However I do not know how to name objects and variables using the iteration number as part of its name.

Comment: Why don't you use an Array?

Comment: Can arrays store entire objects without having to name said objects? If so, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Objects don't have names.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an array that holds all the different objects. In your loop, you can push the object to that array:

```
  const objects = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    objects.push(obj);
  }
```

Now you can get a certain object as:

```
  objects[5] // the sixth object
```

Or you can go over all objects as:

```
  for(const obj of objects)
     console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Does it not matter that the objects will have the same names?

Comment: @jake no, you can only refer to the currently looped object via `obj`, this is only possible inside the loop so there are no conflicts.

Comment: Wouldn't the array be filled with objects all named "obj"? Does that not cause any issues?

Comment: @Jake the "names" of the objects in the array are their **indexes** into the array, numbers that correspond to the order in which they were added. Arrays are a fundamental aspect of programming. As I said in another comment, objects don't *intrinsically* have names however. An object is just an object, and a reference to it can be saved in a variable, an array element as in this example, or in another object property. *Where* a reference is saved does not have any direct effect on the object itself.

Comment: @jake there are also a lot of people named Jake or Jonas, that is not a problem at all as long as there is only one Jonas / Jake at a certain place.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you would like to be able *dinamically create variables with different names*.
It is possible but it is **bad** practice because we create global variables

```
for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
   window['obj' + i] = {i}; //iterate name
}
```

after that you can call *obj1, obj2,* ... and they are all global

I recommend to use local object or Map

```
const localObj = {};
for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
   localObj['obj' + i] = {i}; 
}
```

then you just write *localObj.obj1, localObj.obj2* ...

```
const localMap = new Map();
for (i = 1; i <= x; i++){
   localMap.set('obj'+i, i);
}
```

To get your data: *localMap.get('obj1'), localMap.get('obj2')* ...